# RadioHead Library custom configuration for RFM96 LoRa

Tags: programming, communication, spi, rf

I have a pair of Adafruit RFM96W LoRa Transceiver Breakouts and want to use them with the RadioHead library.

My pair of radios works if I use the example sketches from the adafruit tutorial, but I want to change their default configuration.

From the Datasheet of RFM96:

> For maximum flexibility the user may
>   decide on the spread spectrum modulation **bandwidth (BW)**,
>   **spreading factor (SF)** and **error correction rate (CR)**.

I want to configure the BF, SF and CR. I also want to be sure that the radios are working with the LoRa Modulation and that CRC is enabled.
And how to set Header-Settings?

I did find the method rf.setModemConfig() which gives the capability to change the configuration to library-pre-defined ones, which is not what I want. I want to try different combinations of settings.

I did find the method rf.setModemRegisters() but I did not understand how to use it.

Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter in RH_RF95.h

```
const RH_RF95::ModemConfig myProfile =  { 
  RH_RF95_BW_62_5KHZ | RH_RF95_CODING_RATE_4_5,
  RH_RF95_SPREADING_FACTOR_1024CPS};

rf95.setModemRegisters(&myProfile);
```